# Labelling Tables using Form Recogniser Labelling Tool

Tags: azure, ocr, azure-form-recognizer

I was trying to label tables but while doing that the table will be displayed. If I click the corresponding number of label on keypad,it's not responding. How can I label the detected tables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in Form Recognizer, Layout service will detect tables, and the table information will be stored in the "pageResults" section of the analyze result, you don't need to label it separately.  for example:
"pageResults": [
{
"page": 1,
"tables": [
{
"rows": 2,
"columns": 2,
"cells": [
...

If We are working on advanced table labeling feature, please stay tuned.

-xin (MS Form Recognizer Team)